# Android Action Overflow Button as part of every list element

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am looking to have 3 dot's button along with context menu for each of the Table Row or List Element UI.

I don't want to use Button with Image to do that (as this approach would be inefficient on old devices).
I like to adopt Android approach of they creating Action Overflow menu item for action bar.

Any inputs would be welcome.. i.e how to apply actionbar overflow button to any other parts of my android screen elements such as to each List Element and also Table Row.

Comment: What exactly do you think the Action bar is, other then a bunch of ImageButtons .... What would make this more inefficient on older devices ?

Comment: If I were to do show pop up menu, on different screen sizes etc.. then I am spending more time on replicating the logic of action bar menu.. In case I am aware of using ActionOverflow button outside of actionbar, I hope it would take care of of many migration related issues..also need not package special images (for differnt profiles of devices) needed for 3 dots etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android SDK does not have such widget (till 4.4) The best high quality/professional graphics widget alternatives are

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

I liked the NewQuickAction3D version.  As there is lot of common code between non3d and 3D version, I have merged both of them to dynamically allow switch between any.

More such code for understanding are at

http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme
code for same is at

https://github.com/maonanyue/quickaction

Regards.
Raja Nagendra Kumar,
C.T.O
Android Code Quality Expert